# Jquery Accordion - Make content open with animation

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate, accordion

I have this JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/07fdq3t1/5/

It's almost perfect, except I'd like to have it to where the content is displayed in an animated fashion. Right now it just pops open, but I'd like to have it slowly open. The animation for making it go to the top of the viewport is working great, but I need it to where when someone clicks an element, the content opens up slowly.

Any ideas?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.accordion').click(function(){
        if($(this).next('.container').is(':visible')) {
            $(this).removeClass('show');
            $(this).next('.container').slideUp();
        }
        else {
            $('.accordion').find('.container:visible').slideUp();
            $('.accordion').removeClass('show');
            $(this).addClass('show');
            $(this).next('.container').slideDown();
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
            }, 200);
        }         
    });
});
</script>

<div class="accordion">Heading<span></span></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <div>Sample Content</div>
            <p>Content here....</p>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="accordion">Heading<span></span></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <div>Sample Content</div>
            <p>Content here....</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right. Here is my attempt in solving your problem. Have a look at the fiddle or snippet below.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/pektnku2/).

***Snippet:***

```js
var accordions=null;
var containers=null;
var slideDuration=400;
var scrollDuration=400;
var body=null;
var classNameShow='show';
var classNameAccordion='.accordion';
var classNameContainer='.container';
var dataOffsetTop='offsetTop';
$(document).ready(function(){
 body=$('html, body');
 accordions=$(classNameAccordion);
 containers=$(classNameContainer);
 accordions.each(function(){
  var openedAccordions=accordions.filter(function(){return $(this).hasClass(classNameShow);});
  openedAccordions.removeClass(classNameShow);
  $(this).data(dataOffsetTop,$(this).offset().top);
  openedAccordions.next(classNameContainer).stop(true).slideDown({
   duration:slideDuration,
   complete:function(){openedAccordions.addClass(classNameShow);}
  });
 });
 accordions.click(function(){
  var currentAccordion=$(this);
  var currentContainer=$(this).next(classNameContainer);
  var openedAccordions=accordions.filter(function(){return $(this).hasClass(classNameShow);});
  if(!currentAccordion.hasClass(classNameShow)){
   currentContainer.stop(true).slideDown({
    duration:slideDuration,
    complete:function(){currentAccordion.addClass(classNameShow);}
   });
   body.stop(true).animate({scrollTop:currentAccordion.data(dataOffsetTop)},scrollDuration);
  }else{
   currentContainer.stop(true).slideUp({
    duration:slideDuration,
    complete:function(){currentAccordion.removeClass(classNameShow);}
   });
  }
  containers.not(currentContainer).stop(true).slideUp({
   duration:slideDuration,
   complete:function(){openedAccordions.removeClass(classNameShow);}
  });
 });
});
```

```css
.accordion {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 10px;
 height: 20px;
 border-top: #f0f0f0 1px solid;
 background: #cccccc;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #000;
 font-size: 1em;
}
.accordion span {
 background: #000;
 color: #fff;
}
.show span {
 display: block;
 float: right;
 padding: 10px;
}
.accordion span {
 display: block;
 float: right;
 background: url(http://www.snyderplace.com/demos/images/plus.png) center center no-repeat;
 padding: 10px;
}
.show span {
 background: url(http://www.snyderplace.com/demos/images/minus.png) center center no-repeat;
}
div.container {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 display: none;
}
div.content {
 background: #f0f0f0;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: .9em;
 line-height: 1.5em;
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
div.content ul, div.content p {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 3px;
}
div.content ul li {
 list-style-position: inside;
 line-height: 25px;
}
div.content ul li a {
 color: #555555;
}
div.show + .container {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">Heading<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="content">
  <div>Sample Content</div>
  <p>Content here....</p></div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">Heading<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="content">
  <div>Sample Content</div>
  <p>Content here....</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion show">Heading<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="content">
  <div>Sample Content</div>
  <p>Content here....</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">Heading<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="content">
  <div>Sample Content</div>
  <p>Content here....</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">Heading<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="content">
  <div>Sample Content</div>
  <p>Content here....</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">Heading<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="content">
  <div>Sample Content</div>
  <p>Content here....</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">Heading<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="content">
  <div>Sample Content</div>
  <p>Content here....</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">Heading<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="content">
  <div>Sample Content</div>
  <p>Content here....</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">Heading<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="content">
  <div>Sample Content</div>
  <p>Content here....</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">Heading<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="content">
  <div>Sample Content</div>
  <p>Content here....</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">Heading<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="content">
  <div>Sample Content</div>
  <p>Content here....</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">Heading<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="content">
  <div>Sample Content</div>
  <p>Content here....</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">Heading<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="content">
  <div>Sample Content</div>
  <p>Content here....</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">Heading<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="content">
  <div>Sample Content</div>
  <p>Content here....</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">Heading<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="content">
  <div>Sample Content</div>
  <p>Content here....</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">Heading<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="content">
  <div>Sample Content</div>
  <p>Content here....</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">Heading<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="content">
  <div>Sample Content</div>
  <p>Content here....</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">Heading<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="content">
  <div>Sample Content</div>
  <p>Content here....</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">Heading<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="content">
  <div>Sample Content</div>
  <p>Content here....</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">Heading<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="content">
  <div>Sample Content</div>
  <p>Content here....</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">Heading<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="content">
  <div>Sample Content</div>
  <p>Content here....</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">Heading<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="content">
  <div>Sample Content</div>
  <p>Content here....</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">Heading<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="content">
  <div>Sample Content</div>
  <p>Content here....</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">Heading<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="content">
  <div>Sample Content</div>
  <p>Content here....</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

***Summary:*** (not really)

- The variables are initialized first and foremost. The values of the
  variables are set per need basis, along the way.
- The first **`each`** block is to calculate the destination **`scrollTop`** values based on the **`offset.top()`** positions of ***all*** of the accordion elements. Which is then stored in **`data()`** property for each **`accordion`** element.
- It does that by first collecting the elements that currently have the **`show`** class applied to them and stores them in a variable called **`openedAccordions`**.
- Then it temporarily removes this **`show`** class from them.
- Gets the **`offset.top()`** position of each element and stores in the elements themselves using the convenient **[`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** method provided by jQuery.
- Rather than simply re-applying the **`show`** class using **`addClass()`** method, we actually ***animate*** using the **`slideDown()`** method and only upon completion of the animation, we apply **`show`** using **`addClass()`**.
- This is important because a simple direct application of **`show`** using **`addClass()`** without animation produces an unwanted ***glitch*** the first time you, as a user, interact with this whole component. The ***glitch*** is basically your first already visible **`container`** element that goes away rather instantly, without animation.
- Reason for the approach above is because when things are animating, browser will return current **`offset().top`** position of any given accordion element which may not exactly be what we require i.e. the animation may be in progress and the calculated result coming out of **`offset().top`** may be wrong and hence the browser will scroll to an unwanted position. I hope you understand what I am to trying to say here.
- Moving on ...
- Upon clicking of any of the **`accordion`** elements, some internal variables are defined and their values are set.
- A typical **`if`** clause checking if the element has class named **`show`** applied to it.
- This is the fundamental difference in the approach that you had and the approach I went ahead with. Instead of checking for **`:visible`** state, I chose to simply look for a class' existence on an element.
- The rest of the **`if`** clause should be pretty self-explanatory.
- The last bit is another interesting bit.
- What is happening is that I am using **`slideUp`** to animate the elements so the **`openedAccordions`** elements can hide ***except*** the one that was just clicked. I hope I am making sense here.
- So that is about it. Let me know if you have any questions.

Hope this helps.

P.S. I guess the cool bit for me is how it would re-adjust upon fast clicking. Try increasing the **`scrollDuration`** and **`slideDuration`** values to make all animations go slower and click on random **`accordion`** elements to see what I mean by *re-adjusting*.

Comment: Holy cow, this is unbelievably good. Thank you so much Tahir! Incredible work. I guess I have 2 questions...

1. Is there a way to make it to where multiple accordions can be on a page and act independently of each other? I tried a couple things in the fiddle and couldn't figure it out.

2. Is there a way to make the "scroll to top of viewport" feature only work on mobile/touch devices?

Either way thank you so much!

Comment: **(1)** Yeah I suppose that should not be a problem. It should only be a matter of using the right *selectors*. **(2)** For that you can look into `Modernizr.touch` to see if you are on a touch device, and trigger that. Or, you can sniff which browser the user is using (though not recommended). Plenty of stuff available on internet for that.

Comment: For #1, is there any best way to do that? I imagine I could duplicate the entire script and rename everything, but is there a way to put multiple selectors within this single script? Kind of like:

    `var classNameShow=('show' || 'show2');
    var classNameAccordion=('.accordion' || '.accordion2');
    var classNameContainer=('.container' || '.container2');`

Comment: yeah it can be optimized surely. do you want to create an example HTML / CSS for me (following the same pattern that we have) and I can help you out with the JS bit of it then?

Comment: I am guessing you would not want the `scrollTop` animation for both of them anymore?!

Comment: Actually no I'd love to keep that. This is just a super rough html. In my project the accordions will be in different places on the page, but it'd be great if both of them could keep the scrollTop functionality (if possible).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81747/discussion-between-tahir-ahmed-and-user1610904).

Comment: Tahir would you mind if I posted the fiddle we were working on in a stackoverflow thread to see if someone can figure out that scrolltop issue with multiple accordions? Or let me know if you think you know how. Thanks again for everything.

Comment: hey @user1610904, yeah I am a little occupied. Go ahead, it is always good to see what others think. May be we can get a much better approach from someone else. Go ahead and share with everyone to ask them for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, just use the `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` methods instead of simply adding the `show` class.

[Updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/07fdq3t1/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Just made your slide up remove the show class on completion and the slideDown function be used at the end for your container on show.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.accordion').click(function(){
        if($(this).next('.container').is(':visible')) {
            var self = $(this);
            $(this).next('.container').slideUp(800,function() {
                self.removeClass('show');
            });
        }
        else {
            $('.accordion').find('.container:visible').slideUp();
            $('.accordion').removeClass('show');
            $(this).addClass('show');
            $(this).next('.container').slideDown();
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
            }, 200);
            $(this).slideDown();
        }         
    });
});
```

Here it is running: https://jsfiddle.net/07fdq3t1/6/

Comment: That's super close. In your fiddle, I noticed that when I click an element a second time (_after_ it already slides to the top), it then animates while opening, but is there a way to have it animate opening the first time I click it (while it scrolls to the top)? So basically there'd be two animations (scrolling to top and content opening) at the same time but at different speeds.